# run command dos in script powershell

Tags: powershell

I just started to program with powershell, so I need help. I have this command declared in a variable:

```
$Command_line="sqlcmd -S $SName -U $UName -P $Password -d $DbName -I -i $File"
```

I want execute this command. I tried with the code below, but it didn't work:

```
        Invoke-Expression $Command_line
        # utilisation de son alias
        iex $Command_line
        # utilisation de l'opérateur CALL 
        &$Command_line
        # utilsation de l'opérateur dot-sourced
        .$Command_line
        # On executant la variable par $ExecutionContext
        $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript($Command_line)
```

I also tried this:

```
#Start-Process "$Command_line"
```

And:

```
$Command_line= "cmd.exe /C ""sqlcmd -S $SName -U $UName -P $Password -d $DbName -I -i $File"
            writeLog $logFile "Execution de la commande $Command_line" #Affichage de la commande


            #$NomExe = "cmd.exe"
            #$WorkingDir = "C:\"

            #Lancement de l'exe
            #start-process -FilePath $NomExe -ArgumentList $Command_line -workingdirectory $WorkingDir
```

However, I get an error as shown by [this link](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1874890/general-developpement/programmation-systeme/windows/scripts-batch/powershell-executer-commande-cmd-inclue-script-shellpower/).

Comment: just try this:
&cmd /c sqlcmd -S $SName -U $UName -P $Password -d $DbName -I -i $File

Comment: You don't even need to do that much. @D.J. All you need to do is call the executable: `sqlcmd.exe ...`

Comment: its work with  &cmd /c sqlcmd -S $SName -U $UName -P $Password -d $DbName -I -i $File but i can't put  this  sqlcmd -S $SName -U $UName -P $Password -d $DbName -I -i $File in one variable

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need to do:

```
sqlcmd -S $SName -U $UName -P $Password -d $DbName -I -i $File
```

You don't need a quoted string or any fancy commands. Just use the command line.

Since you are in PowerShell, I would also suggest you may be able to use the SQLPS module.

Comment: If they're on SQL Server 2008, there is a snapin: `Add-PSSnapin -Name SqlServerCmdletSnapin100`

Comment: I have SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Given your example:

```
$Command_line="sqlcmd -S $SName -U $UName -P $Password -d $DbName -I -i $File"
```

You can execute it as such:

```
& ([scriptblock]::Create($Command_line))
```

[I'd suggest never using `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Comment: i try with & ([scriptblock]::Create($Command_line)) didn't work

Comment: i get this :./StoredProcedure.ps : Le terme «./StoredProcedure.ps» n'est pas reconnu comme
nom d'applet de commande, fonction, fichier de script ou programme exécutable.
Vérifiez l'orthographe du nom, ou si un chemin d'accès existe, vérifiez que le
chemin d'accès est correct et réessayez.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ ./StoredProcedure.ps
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./StoredProcedure.ps:String) []
   , CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException